SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module using TypeScript in next.js
I am using Nest.js and TypeScript for the backend of my app. However, when I try to build the project using docker-compose, I get such an error:
    /app/src/users/users.entity.ts:1
backend_1   | import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BeforeInsert } from 'typeorm';
backend_1   | ^^^^^^
backend_1   | 
backend_1   | SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
backend_1   |     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:76:18)
backend_1   |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1283:20)
backend_1   |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1328:27)
backend_1   |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
backend_1   |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
backend_1   |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
backend_1   |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
backend_1   |     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
backend_1   |     at tryToRequire (/app/node_modules/typeorm/util/src/util/ImportUtils.ts:21:17)
backend_1   |     at importOrRequireFile (/app/node_modules/typeorm/util/src/util/ImportUtils.ts:35:25)

Here's my tsconfig file:
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs", // Use CommonJS for compatibility with Node.js
    "moduleResolution": "node", // Explicitly set module resolution to Node.js style
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src", // Root directory of TypeScript files
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

And Dockerfile, if needed
FROM node:18

# Install wait-for-it
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh /usr/bin/wait-for-it
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/wait-for-it

WORKDIR /app

# Copy and install dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Start the application, waiting for the database to be ready
CMD ["wait-for-it", "db:5432", "--", "npm", "run", "start"]

I've seen the solution of a similar problem that refers to 'ormconfig' file. However, I couldn't find it anywhere in the project.

Kinda unrelated but you don't need wait-for-it inside your Dockerfile, just add depends_on tag to your docker-compose file
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/#example

One way you could do it, is by not using NPM to run your project to begin with.
Instead you should make sure you add RUN npm run build to the Dockerfile to compile the project, and then e.g. CMD ["dist/main.js"] to run the compiled bundle

don't really get it:) could you please edit the Dockerfile in my question for more clarity?
